# Money filter on shopify not working on scripts

Tags: javascript, shopify

Hi. So for some reason, I'm trying to subtract my variant prices. It's working but the money filter isnt.

```
console.log ( {{ product.variants[0].price | minus: product.variants[1].price }} );
```

> 80604

The number above is what I'm being able to get. Adding | money filter to the code returns nothing. For example:

```
console.log ( {{ product.variants[0].price | minus: product.variants[1].price | money }} );
```

Any workaround I can do please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding the `money` filter to that command will give a rendered code that looks something like this:

```
console.log( $806.04 )
```

This is not legal Javascript, and you will probably be seeing an error in your console relating to this line.

Fortunately, Shopify has the `json` filter, which is good for more than just converting Liquid objects to JavaScript Object Notation. *Any* Liquid variable that is passed through this filter will be converted to a javascript-legal form.  This means that text will be wrapped in quotation marks, any special characters will be properly escaped, blank values will become `null`, etc.  I strongly recommend that developers ALWAYS use the `json` filter whenever you need to pass variables from Liquid to Javascript.

So to fix your code, simply use:

```
console.log ( {{ product.variants[0].price | minus: product.variants[1].price | money | json }} );
```

Comment: I added the | json filter earlier but removed the | money filter, that was so stupid of me haha. This perfectly worked! Thank you!